# Rhiny: combine several uiOutput("select") / SelectInput() with conditionalPanel()

Tags: shiny-server, shiny

My brand new Shiny App has one sidePanel with two dynamic SelectInput() functions. Depending on which Panel is active, the respective uiOutput("select") dynamic SelectInput should be use. I read this could be done with conditionalPanel() - but I cannot figure out how ... non of the examples I found combine uiOutput("select")/SelectInput(), all use SelectInput directly in the Pane...

Please, can anyone help me, how I have to change the code to include  conditionalPanel()- if this is what's necessary. Thank a lot for any advice and help!!!!

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Table Overviews'),
sidebarPanel(
  uiOutput("select1"),
  br(),
  uiOutput("select2")
),
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Panel 1", 
             fluidRow(
               column(6, h4("Tablel"), tableOutput("Table1")),
               column(6, div(style = "height:300px")),
               fluidRow(
                 column(6,h4("Table2"), tableOutput("Table2")),
                 column(6,h4("Table3"), tableOutput("Table3")))
             )), 
    tabPanel("Panel 2", 
             fluidRow(
               column(6, h4("Table4"), tableOutput("Table4")),
               column(6, div(style = "height:300px")),
               fluidRow(
                 column(6,h4("Table5"), tableOutput("Table5")),
                 column(6,h4("Table6"), tableOutput("Table6")))
             ))
  )
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
## two different SelectInputs to select from two different lists 
output$select1 <- renderUI({
selectInput("dataset1", "Overview1", as.list(files1))
 })

 output$select2 <- renderUI({
 selectInput("dataset2", "Overview2", as.list(files2))
 })


 ## Output of the first SelectInput
 output$Table1 <- renderTable({
    f1 <- function1(input$dataset1)
 f1[[1]]
 })

 output$Table2 <- renderTable({
  f1 <- function1(input$dataset1)
  f1[[2]]
 })

 output$Table3 <- renderTable({
  f1 <- function1(input$dataset1)
  f1[[3]]
 })

 # Output of the second SelectInput
 output$Table4<- renderTable({
  f2 <- function2(input$dataset2)
  f2[[3]]
 })

 output$Table5 <- renderTable({
  f2  <- function2(input$dataset2)
  f2[[2]]
 })

 output$Table6 <- renderTable({
  f2  <- function2(input$dataset2)
  f2[[1]]
 })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out - it's really simple. Thanks to all comments for my various questions, thanks a lot to everyone!!!

All that's needed to be changed in the UI.R:

```
  conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels == Panel 1",       
                   uiOutput("select_twb")),
  br(),
  conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels == Panel 2",       
                   uiOutput("select_twbx"))
```